# Different representation of valid HTML 5 code in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-browser

The following code displays differently in Chrome and Firefox:

```css
#category-chooser {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="btn-group-vertical" id="category-chooser">
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
  <div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-default">
    a lot of content... foo bar foo bar
   </button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" id="choose-furniture">
   <button class="btn btn-default">
    short
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
  <div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-default">
    short
   </button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
   <button class="btn btn-default">
    a lot of content... foo bar foo bar
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The bootstrap classes seem to do something strange here. However, on the [bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns), the example seems to work fine across browsers.

In Chrome, the "columns" are spaced out proportionally to the content. In Firefox, all columns have the same width.

Comment: Which one is the desired result?

Comment: I think it looks nicer with equally-spaced columns, but either would be fine. I am more interested in what the problem is.

Comment: Are you using a doctype? Which one?

Comment: This is html5 (`<DOCTYPE html>`).

Comment: That would be incorrect unless it's a typo. Note the exclamation mark: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: It was a typo, sorry for that. (JSFiddle should use HTML 5 anyway?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`btn-group-justified` makes use of `display: table`, however that CSS is overridden by `btn-group-vertical` to `display: block`. I guess browsers handle `btn-group` (`display: table-cell`) differently when the parent container does not display as table.

Your codes look fine, the Bootstrap sample does not show mixed use of `btn-group-vertical` and `btn-group-justified`. I believe it is the limitation not described.

I would suggest removing `btn-group-vertical` and adjust the `border-radius` yourself.